# Using HTP.P in ATP oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql, mod-plsql

I've just started checking out the ATP database in oracles cloud.

I have an old pl/sql proc that I want to put on the ATP database.

Happily the procedure with calls to htp.p compiled with no errors...but how do I find the URL to use to get to my procedure?

(And BTW no the proc isn't something that can just be converted into a restful web service through apex.)

Comment: As I understand it, ATP is just a cloud database - it's not attached to a web server, so there's nowhere for HTP.P to print to. I really would recommend exposing it as a restful service through ORDS, but maybe there's some reason why that wouldn't work. https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-http-headers-and-ords-specific-bind-variables

Answer (score 0):

The answer I've gone with for this is that the ATP database comes with ORDS configuired and ready to use.
You can expose pl/sql procedures to requests through ORDS.  This does require some manual work for each procedure but not a huge amount.

You will need to set up a module in ORDS and a template for each get/put etc call you want to send through to your procedure.

Its documented pretty well here:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-remote-procedure-call-rpc-and-output-parameters
This is using the command line for everything - I've found it easier to use the restful data services available through apex to get a GUI interface to use to set this up.  I believe there is a GUI available through sql developer too.